# Startar uma aplicação MVC através de um Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, services

Eu tenho uma aplicação que foi desenvolvida no padrão DDD, que usa a injeção de dependências, ela esta funcionando normalmente, porem precisei adicionar um projeto do tipo Windows Service que sera o start da aplicação, o problema é que se faço uma referencia a minha controller do MVC (onde da incio a todo o processo) a Injeção de dependencia nao funciona (as variáveis que fazem referencias as classe das outras camadas não são carregadas e ficam como nula) acredito que seja pq quando faço isso o arquivo global.asax (onde fica o mapeamento a injeção nao é execultado), gostaria de saber se através do meu windows service eu consigo start o projeto MVC como um todo? acredito que dessa forma ira funcionar as demais funcionalidades.

Controller do MVC:

```
 private readonly IAwbApplication _awbApplication;
    private readonly IMovimentoApplication _movimentoApplication;
    public static List<string> LogAplicacao = new List<string>();

    public AwbController(IAwbApplication awbApplication, IMovimentoApplication movimentoApplication)
    {
        _awbApplication = awbApplication;
        _movimentoApplication = movimentoApplication;

    }

    public  void Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var movimentos = _movimentoApplication.ObterMovimentos();

            foreach (var movimento in movimentos)
            {
                var listaStatusWebServiceGol = _awbApplication.Pesquisar(movimento.nr_AWB.Trim()).ToList();
                var listaStatusMovimento = _awbApplication.StatusPorMovimento(movimento.id_Movimento);

                for (var i = listaStatusMovimento.Count(); i < listaStatusWebServiceGol.Count(); i++)
                {
                    listaStatusWebServiceGol.ToList()[i].id_Movimento = movimento.id_Movimento;
                    _awbApplication.InserirMovimentoTracking(listaStatusWebServiceGol.ToList()[i]);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            GravarLogAplicacaoValidacao(ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            var log = new GeradorLogUtil();
            log.EscreverLog(LogAplicacao, @"C:\TrackingAwb\LogErro.txt");
        }


    }
```

Windows Service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"O Serviço começou");
        ExecutarRotina();
      //  _worker = new Timer((ExecutarRotina), null, 0, _interval);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"O Serviço parou");
    }

    public void ExecutarRotina()
    {
        // preciso chamar o projeto MVC aqui

    }
```

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você quer dizer com startar uma aplicação. Você está se referindo ao host startar o pool da aplicação? Acessar uma Action da Controller? Qual é o objetivo disso?

Comment: Dentro da minha controler eu tenho um metodo Index, que  eu gostaria de rodar so que quando eu chamo dele atraves do windows service, as dependências não são carregadas, logo as chamadas para os outros metodos de outras camadas da erro, acredito que isso ocorre pq quando chamado o metodo de uma outra aplicação, as configurações que da injeção de dependência que fica no global.asax nao é executada, por isso quis saber se tem como executar o MVC de forma geral, consegui explicar o que eu quero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você precisa simular um acesso a sua aplicação MVC, você precisa fazer um request para mesma, não basta executar um método da classe. Afinal, é uma aplicação, não uma biblioteca e depende de todo um ambiente para funcionar.

Se essa rotina é necessária tanto para sua aplicação MVC, quanto para o seu Windows Service, ela deveria ser implementada em outra camada compartilhada por ambos.

E, se o objetivo do serviço é apenas "fazer um hit" na aplicação MVC... ele não precisaria nem estar rodando, bastava agendar uma task no próprio windows para isso.

Mas vamos lá, em sua proposta para alcançar seu objetivo basta fazer o request para a url da aplicação.

```
public void ExecutarRotina()
{
    string mvcUrl = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com"; // endereço da sua aplicação MVC;

    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(mvcUrl);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        var httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: @JhonatasSilva, ficou alguma dúvida?

Comment: cara me ajudou muito, funcionou obrigado, só uma duvida, testei usando o endereço com localhost msm e funcionou, se eu colocar isso em outra máquina funcionaria tbm só especificando a porta?

Comment: Só vai funcionar com localhost se o serviço estiver rodando no mesmo servidor da aplicação mvc, caso contrário vc tem que informar o endereço correto